# Python - script made with gym does not work on Mac

Tags: python, deep-learning, pycharm, reinforcement-learning

I am following the tutorial [here](https://becominghuman.ai/lets-build-an-atari-ai-part-1-dqn-df57e8ff3b26) to learn Deep Reinforcement Learning (I am very new to the topic).

When I try to run the script below on my Macbook it returns me an Import Error (`ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down`).
I tried to run it from the Mac terminal and also in Pycharm with the same result.
I tried also with other deep learning scripts and the error is the same (it seems not related to this script in particular).

Could you please help me understanding where I am wrong?

Script:

```
# Import the gym module
import gym

# Create a breakout environment
env = gym.make('BreakoutDeterministic-v4')
# Reset it, returns the starting frame
frame = env.reset()
# Render
env.render()

is_done = False
while not is_done:
  # Perform a random action, returns the new frame, reward and whether the game is over
  frame, reward, is_done, _ = env.step(env.action_space.sample())
  # Render
  env.render()
```

Error below:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.6 /Users/marcogdepinto/PycharmProjects/PlayPong/pong.py
2018-05-12 18:58:11.915 Python[567:12594] ApplePersistenceIgnoreState: Existing state will not be touched. New state will be written to (null)
Exception ignored in: <bound method SimpleImageViewer.__del__ of <gym.envs.classic_control.rendering.SimpleImageViewer object at 0x10b65bc88>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gym/envs/classic_control/rendering.py", line 347, in __del__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gym/envs/classic_control/rendering.py", line 343, in close
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/window/cocoa/__init__.py", line 281, in close
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 770, in close
ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "*Try adding `env.close()` at the end of your programs, in my scenario,
>   it works nice*"

[src](https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/893#issuecomment-369519156)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the lines below at the end of your program, the Error is raised during GC of the gym module.

```
try:
    del env
except ImportError:
    pass
```